# I'm having trouble trying to create a backup of a MySql database, using Node.js. How can I resolve this error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to perform automatic backups using Node.js and the mysqldump package. It does the backup a few times, however, sometimes it generates the error below and shuts down the application.

**The error:**

> Error: ENOENT no such file or directory, open '/root/backups/backup_781926531667722261_1611607259273.sql.gz.temp'

**My code:**

```
const mysqldump = require('mysqldump')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const Guild = require('../../mongodb/Schemas/Guild.js')

const moment = require('moment')
moment.locale('pt-BR')

module.exports = async (client) => {    
    global.backupInterval = setInterval(async () => {
        const guilds = await Guild.find({ "backupStatus": true })

        guilds.forEach(async guild => {    
            console.log(path.join(process.cwd(), 'backups', 'a'))        
            const channel = client.channels.cache.get(guild.backupChannel)
            if (!channel) return
            const timestamp = Date.now()
            const dumpfile = `backup_${channel.guild.id}_${timestamp}.sql.gz`
            mysqldump({
                connection: {
                    host: guild.mysqlcon.ip,
                    user: guild.mysqlcon.user,
                    password: guild.mysqlcon.senha,
                    database: guild.mysqlcon.db,
                },
                dumpToFile: path.join(process.cwd(), 'backups', dumpfile),
                compressFile: true
            }).then(async () => {                
                await channel.send(`${moment(new Date()).format('LLLL')}`, { files: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'backups', dumpfile)] })
                fs.unlinkSync(`./backups/${dumpfile}`)
            }, () => {}).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                channel.send('Backup não realizado no servidor pois a conexão não pôde ser estabelecida.')
            })
        })
    }, global.backupTime * 60000)
}
```

Comment: Try to create the folder `backups` in your project.
Or try to use `path` module and __dirName like this `path.join(__dirname, '/backups')`

Comment: I already have the backups folder in my project.

Comment: You can't `await` inside a `forEach` loop (Well, you can write the code and it won't throw an error, but it won't await). Try with a `for( let guild of guilds )` loop

Comment: Ok, Jeremy, I will try it.

Comment: Even using the for, my problem has not been solved.

Comment: Please update your code in the post to the recent one with `for` and don't mixup `than/catch` with `await`